# After button animation, how do I make the next activity wait a couple of seconds?

Tags: android, animation, button, time

I want to know if there is a way to make the app wait like 2-3 seconds after it does a button animation (pulsingAnimation.start()) so that after those three seconds it will do the next code in line which is to create an intent and start a new activity/finish the last one. Here is my code. Please help, thanks!

```
final Button Metric = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout6);
    final ObjectAnimator pulsingAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(r,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.2f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.2f));

    pulsingAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    pulsingAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
    Metric.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            pulsingAnimation.start();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Metric.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using a delayed handler 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

eg:

```
handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sleep for some milliseconds with the Thread.sleep(milliseconds) function.
Take a look to this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this:

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Metric.class);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
        }
    }, 3000); // 3000 - 3 seconds, 2000 - 2 seconds
```